# Selecting a filename with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am using a code for creating folders and moving .jpgs in them, and I need a little help with including a regex in one of the lines. The code is the following:

```py
import glob
import os.path
import shutil

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

files = glob.glob('*.jpg')
for filename in files:
    name = filename[0:7]
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, name))
    except OSError:
        pass
    shutil.move(filename, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, name, filename))
```

As it is, it basically takes every .jpg from the directory and creates a new folder for it based on the first 6 letters of the filename `name = filename[0:7]`. Instead, I want to name the folders using a regex that captures all the letters before the underscore. So if I have a picture named `examplename_53853532_5353.jpg`, I want the script to create a folder called `examplename` and dump the picture in it.

I tried the following `name = filename[r".+?(?=_)"]` , but it doesn't work. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.split()`

**Ex:**

```
import glob
import os.path
import shutil

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

files = glob.glob('*.jpg')
for filename in files:
    name = filename.split("_")[0]
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, name))
    except OSError:
        pass
    shutil.move(filename, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, name, filename))
```

---

If you need Regex.

```
import re

s = "examplename_53853532_5353.jpg"
pattern = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Z]+)(?=_)")

print(pattern.match(s).group(1))  # --> examplename
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use regex, you're going to need to use the `re` module, or some other module for actually processing regex. The `r"strings"` that you appear to be trying to use aren't *regex* strings, they're *raw* strings (meaning that certain escape characters aren't processed).

As @Rakesh points out, `str.split()` is an easier solution for this particular case, and doesn't involve pulling in the `re` module when you don't have to. But for the sake of clarity, here's a regex expression that will get everything up until the first underscore:

```
import re
...
for filename in files:
    name = re.search(r'([^_]*)_', filename).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
[^\/\\]+$
```

> Find everything at the end of the string which is not a forward slash nor backslash